# Running another notebook inside a notebook which is connected to git

Tags: scala, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

In our company we learned to connect our notebook to git repository, however there is an issue.

Running a notebook inside another notebook. This is the way that we have discovered, however this solution cant go into production because it included an employee username in the path.

What is/are solution to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relative paths for `%run` command. For example:

- `./name` for notebook in current directory
- `../name` for notebook in parent directory
- `../../name` for notebook in two levels higher
- `subdir/name` for notebook in sub-directory with name `subdir`

You can also consider to use [arbitrary files support in Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules), although it's mostly for Python & R modules.

Comment: That is working!!! Awesome!