# Unable to run secondary notebook from Azure DevOps repo in Databricks due to 'file not found' error

Tags: git, azure-devops, databricks, databricks-repos, magic-command

I have my Azure DevOps repo cloned into Databricks. I'm trying to run the %run on a secondary notebook in the repo. When I attempt to execute the %run command on the secondary notebook, I consistently receive a file not found error.

I'm working on the main branch of my repository, and all changes have been committed. Could anyone suggest what might be going wrong here? Am I perhaps overlooking some specifics related to path formatting in Databricks or Azure DevOps? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

I've been using the absolute path to the file, which I obtain by copying directly from the file in question, following this format:

<sub>/Repos/[repoName]/[folder1]/[folder2]/[notebookName]</sub>

However, the system returns the following exception:

```
Exception: File `'/Repos/[repoName]/[folder1]/[folder2]/[notebookName]'` not found.
```

Comment: Are you able to see the file under `Repos`.  try using
`%sh ls /Workspace/Repos/path_to_notebook_folder`

Comment: @JayashankarGS yes - I see the notebook I'm trying to run

Comment: Why do you use absolute path? Just use relative paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780766/running-another-notebook-inside-a-notebook-which-is-connected-to-git/70782763#70782763

Comment: @AlexOtt using relative path `../[folder2]` did the trick. Must be something in the path related to the repository. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relative path `../[folder2]` worked.